# How to add color to part of igraph vertex?

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I have two data files. One file contains all the date relationship like "A B", which means A has connection with B. I use this relationship to create the network with `igraph`. The other one has the data which I want to color these nodes in the `igraph` and of course all of these data exist in the first file. 
I wrote these codes below but I'm not sure how to color them.

```
code:

library(igraph)
dat <-read.graph("data.txt", format = "edgelist",  directed = FALSE )
answer <-read.table("color.txt")
plot.igraph(dat,vertex.size =3,vertex.label=NA,layout=layout.regionld(g,circular=T))

For example：

data.txt:

A B

B C

D A

A C

Color.txt

A

B
```

I want to draw network with line connected between two data in each row in data.txt and also color the data in the color.txt in the network.

I want to know how could I color these data from the answer in the `igraph`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add the example. Hope it helps understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color the nodes that are in `Color.txt` like this:

```
library(igraph)
dat <- readLines(n=4)
A B
B C
D A
A C
col <- readLines(n=2)
A
B
g <- make_graph(unlist(strsplit(dat, " ", T)))
plot(g, vertex.color = V(g)$name %in% col)
```

Comment: but console showed could not find function make_graph

Comment: Figure it out. Thanks